# What's the negative statement for "used to"?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

For the routine/regular work in the past, we say :

```
I used to get up early in the morning when I was 8 year old.
```

What will be the negative statement for this?

I heard people saying :

```
I did not use to get up....
I would not get up......
```

Both are same ? What's the correct negative statement ? Please explain.

Comment: I never got up early in the morning when I was 8 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative form of the construction pronounced /'yustə/ (and spelled *used to*)
is pronounced /'dɪdṇyustə/. That's what you're hearing, and it's correct.

The problem is that it's a new construction and it doesn't have a satisfactory spelling yet.

You **could** spell it *didn't **used** to,* with a past participle *used,* but that looks wrong,
because *did* has to be followed by an infinitive, **not** a past participle.

Or, you **could** spell it *didn't **use** to,* with an infinitive *use,* but that looks wrong, **too**,
because the infinitive *use* is pronounced /yuz/, with /z/, **not** /yus/, with /s/, like the idiom /'yustə/.

So here's the situation. The construction is very frequent in speech, but it's avoided in writing,
because it distracts fluent readers, and they're the ones you don't want to distract.

Comment: I tend to use "didn't use to" when I didn't use to in the past but I do now.  But if we were talking about how Joe used to go to the ice cream shop with his mother when he was young, but we did not have that tradition, I wouldn't day, "We didn't used to do that." I'd say, "We never did that."

Comment: +1 .. But I think you'll find that it is in fact a very old construction ([*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio101murruoft#page/472/mode/2up),**20**) which gradually fell out of use (!) in the 19th and early 20th centuries, surviving only in the past-tense and deverbalized past-participle forms, which took on new pronunciations.

Comment: It's **not** a new construction, and it has never fallen out of use, at least according to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+didn't+use+to%2CI+didn't+used+to%2CI+used+not+to&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20did%20not%20use%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20did%20not%20used%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20used%20not%20to%3B%2Cc0). What may have happened was that the pronunciation of *used to* and *didn't use to* in this context changed some time in the early 19th century, encouraging people to spell it differently.